# Deploying Ruby on rails applications using GIT in AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.1, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking at ways to have a setup for complete development and deployment cycle by using Git to have code versions and then transfer a that code(push) into an AWS elastic Beanstalk instance... I would also like to know of any other methods that includes 'rubber' setup. can you please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of November 1, 2012, Elastic Beanstalk now natively supports Rails and Sinatra apps running Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.3. Phusion Passenger is the application server. Git deployment is included, and the EB command line tools have been updated.

Here is the [announcement](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/11/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-runs-ruby-and-integrates-with-amazon-vpc/):

Here is a [good tutorial](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html)